# Forcing union alignment inside struct

Tags: c, gcc, struct, embedded, pic

How do I define a **struct** with **union** inside, so that it occupies only 1 byte? I tried to add `__attribute__((packed))` everywhere, but it did not help.

Here are the members of struct:

```
struct
{
    int blockNumber: 1 __attribute__((packed));
    int shallBe1: 1 __attribute__((packed)); // should be set to 1 per ISO 14443-4
    int nadFollowing: 1 __attribute__((packed)); // always 0 in our software
    int cidFollowing: 1 __attribute__((packed)); // always 0 in our software
    union
    {
        int chaining: 2 __attribute__((packed)); // i-block
        int ackNak: 2 __attribute__((packed)); // r-block
        int deselectOrWtx: 2 __attribute__((packed)); // s-block
    } __attribute__((packed));
    int blockType: 2 __attribute__((packed));
} pcb __attribute__((packed));
```

The **sizeof(pcb)** returns more than 1, while I need it to occupy exactly one byte.

Here's how I test for struct size:

```
BYTE testpcb[sizeof(pcb) == 1 ? 0 : -1];
```

If I get an error during build, then the struct is not 1 byte.

Comment: try to make the underlying type of the bitfields `uint8_t` instead (or `unsigned char`, if it's not available).

Comment: No luck, size is still not 1 byte.

Comment: Each `int` is two bytes and you have five of them in the `struct` even without the `union`. I don't see how you can expect the whole thing to be just a single byte.

Comment: I expect each member to be 1 or 2 bits only because they are bitfields.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that, but they will still be bitfields within a two-byte `int`. Is that `union` really necessary inside the struct or could you define a generic 2-bit field which you can move to a union if necessary? It's only effectively giving alternative names for the same two bits.

Comment: But then why changing their type to `unsigned char` didn't help? I wanted to preserve `union` in order to improve code readability.

Comment: The problem is that structure packing removes padding *bytes*. It doesn't pack the bits of bit fields. I did some experimenting, and the smallest size I could get was 3 bytes: a byte for the first 4 elements, a byte for the union, and a byte for the `blockType`. I don't think it's possible to do better because the `union` will always be treated as a separate entity that occupies at least one byte.

Comment: Also, as you've tagged PIC and are trying to get a single byte, you are using XC8 aren't you? With XC16 or XC32 you'll never get less than the size of the underlying storage unit.

Comment: I see. No, I'm using the compiler for PIC24. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Every compiler treats bitfields differently, and not all compilers have clearly-defined methods of controlling how bitfields will be packed. When using bitfields, getting structure offsets to pack the way you want can be difficult, and sometimes is just straight-up impossible.

If I were you, I'd treat it as a u8 and mask appropriately when required. It's non-ideal, but in my experience what you'd use here.